# Why do I receive a "signal SIGSEGV, segmentation fault" when I try to delete last elements from doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, reference

This is a programming assignment from university. The main program was given to me by the professor. I have to create the dlist.h. When I debug, I receive this segmentation error. I also have this:

```
get (dl=..., val=<error reading variable>) at dlist.h:37
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>


    
struct DListElem {          //element of the list
    int info;
    DListElem * prev;
    DListElem * next;
};
    
struct DList{               //just stores pointers to first and last elements of the list
    DListElem * first;
    DListElem * last;
};


void initializeDList(DList & dl){  //Iinitializes dl as empty list

    dl.first = nullptr;
    dl.last = nullptr;
}

void put(DList& dl, int val){  //insert a new element with value val at the beginning of the list.

    DListElem* front_elem = new DListElem;
    front_elem ->info = val;
    front_elem -> prev = nullptr;
    front_elem -> next = dl.first;
    dl.first = front_elem;
            
    if(dl.last==NULL) dl.last=dl.first;
}

bool get(DList& dl, int& val){
    /*Removes an item (if possible) from the end of the list. The value of the last 
    element is returned by the val parameter, the memory for the list element 
    is released. The return value indicates whether an item could be retrieved, 
    i.e. it returns false for an empty list and true otherwise.*/
    
    if(dl.last==nullptr) return false;
    if (dl.first==dl.last){             //if there is only 1 element
        val = dl.last -> info;
        DListElem* buffer = new DListElem;
        buffer = dl.last;
        dl.last = nullptr;
        dl.first = nullptr; 
        delete (buffer);
    }
    else{
        val = dl.last -> info;
        DListElem* buffer = new DListElem;
        buffer = dl.last;
        dl.last = dl.last -> prev;
        dl.last -> next = nullptr;         //this part seems to still be the problem
        delete (buffer);
        
    };
    return true;
}
```

And this is my main program:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "dlist.h"
 using namespace std;

 int main (int argc, char *argv[])  {

DList queue;
initializeDList (queue);
```

*inserts 5 values*

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
 cout << "put: " << 10 * i << endl; 
 put (queue, 10 * i);
 }
```

*removes 3 values and prints them to console*

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++){
    int value;    
    if (get (queue, value))
    cout << "     get: " << value << endl;
}
```

*I guess these are necessary:*

```
  cin.sync ();
  cin.get ();
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Either use `malloc`+`free` (if you're in C) or `new`+`delete`. Dont mix both.

Comment: In `get()`, when deleting the last (only) element you do `dl.last = NULL;` - it seems you also need to do `dl.first = NULL;`.

Comment: `#ifndef _DLIST_H_` -- Your teacher should be aware that identifiers starting with underscores are reserved for the compiler.  Thus the code shown is ill-formed, even though it may work.  There are other issues such as using `NULL` instead of `nullptr`.

Comment: I changed the code according to your recommendations but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @tokyo Recommendations for your code to work would go in the answer section, not the comment section.  The comment section is to comment on your code.

Comment: `DListElem* buffer = new DListElem;` has no place in a function that removes stuff from the list. Change `DListElem* buffer = new DListElem; buffer = dl.last;` to `DListElem* buffer = dl.last;`

Answer (score 0):

okay, the issue was with the function put(); I didn't implement it well enough and it produced only a single linked list; consequently, dl.last became null in the function get() and the expression dl.last -> next = nullptr; was the reason for the problem;

**this is the corrected put()**

```
    put (DList & dl, int val)
    {               //insert a new element with value val at the beginning of the      list.

    DListElem *front_elem = new DListElem;
    front_elem->info = val;
    front_elem->prev = nullptr;
    front_elem->next = dl.first;
    if (dl.first != nullptr && dl.first->next == nullptr)
    dl.last = dl.first;
    if (dl.first != nullptr)
    dl.first->prev = front_elem;
    dl.first = front_elem;

     }
```